# Fastest way to calculate $a^\binom{n}{r}\bmod M$ if $\binom{n}{r}$ is very large

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, exponentiation, modular-forms

What is the fastest way to calculate $a^\binom{n}{r} \bmod M$? Here $M$ is a prime number.

So far the best approach I can get is to use $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}$ and then apply product rule of modulo calculation. And I also use Dynamic approach to store calculated result but still this method take time of order Big-$O(n\cdot r)$. And I want faster than this (like logarithmic order). Is it possible?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I have updated the formatting this time.

Comment: @sil: I guess your edit is wrong and the OP means
$$a^{\binom{n}{r}}\bmod M$$

Comment: @gammatester Hm could be, hard to tell from a^nCr... let's change it, OP should check the edit.

Comment: This is related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2845533/number-raised-to-power-binomial-coefficient-whole-modulo

Comment: What is motivation/source behind this problem?